# ASPX View Engine

Tags: asp.net, razor, openxml, spark-view-engine, nhaml

So the [Razor view engine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) is open source and can be used outside MVC specific implimentations. However, for my specific project (Where I want to enable this functionality inside [WordprocessingML](http://openxmldeveloper.org/) Razor won't work as it tries to be smart and work out what is markup and what is Razor code.

Let me clarify, Razor could work inside WordprocessingML as long as you want to give up the idea of opening and editing the documents in MS Word (Or other openXML compliant editor).

For that reason, I was thinking that if you could encapsulate each line of code in XML tags of some kind, you could overcome that, but that is effectively just the ASPX View Engine.

I think that would work perfectly for what I want to do while supporting the full power of C# if required. The problem is that I don't think the ASPX View Engine is available for direct implimentation.

On the [ASP.Net site](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3), Microsoft lists some other view engines like [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/), [NHaml](http://code.google.com/p/nhaml/), or [NDjango](http://ndjango.org/).

Have you used these before?
Which would you recommend?
Which would you avoid?
Any other ideas would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance